# On the construction of an algorithm for serial length compression of strings

Tags: python, algorithm, compression

Repeat until string s is empty.

If there are two or more consecutive letters from the beginning of s

```
・Define n as the number of consecutive pieces.
・Display 'ns' and delete n characters from the beginning.
```

If two or more characters are not consecutive

```
・Memorize how many characters are not consecutive and display '-ns'.
・Then remove ns from the string.
```

Example.

```
input = 'abcaaaaaaaaaaaaaab'
output = '-3abc12a-1b'

input = 'AaAaAAAAa'
output = '-4AaAa4A-1a'
```

If you are familiar with the algorithm, it would be helpful to know.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: why AAAAAA becomes 4A?

Comment: sorry. 
input = 'AaAaAAAAAAAAA'.
I will correct it.

Comment: Entirely close to [PackBits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to identify the different chunks of the string, and then use the `re.sub` callback to format the chunk as specified:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"(.)\1+|(?:(.)(?!\2))+")

def encode_match(match):
    a, b = match.group(0, 1)
    return f"{'-' * (not b)}{len(a)}{b or a}"

def encode(s):
    return regex.sub(encode_match, s)

print(encode('abcaaaaaaaaaaaab')) # '-3abc12a-1b'
print(encode('AaAaAAAAa'))        # '-4AaAa4A-1a'
```